# How to sort an array and remove the duplicates or vice versa in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an unsorted array. What is the best method to remove all the duplicates of an element if present and sort them?

Example:

```
{10,10,50,20,45,60,25,25,90}
```

Output:

```
{10,20,25,45,50,90}
```

Comment: use/add elements to a TreeSet

Comment: Please define "best".

Comment: There is a fantastic tool called Google.Try it.

Comment: Hello Cool Guy I know how to sort them using bubble sort i dont know how to remove duplicates at a time so i asked this question Cool Guy

Comment: Thank you jp-jee for your idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TreeSet` to do this .Add all the elements of the `array` to `TreeSet` and storing it back to the `array`.

#### Code

```
Integer[] arr = {10,10,50,20,45,60,25,25,90};
TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    tree.add(arr[i]);
}

arr = new Integer[tree.size()];
tree.toArray(arr);
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + "\t");
}
```

#### Output

```
10  20  25  45  50  60  90
```